# What does the difference between 'torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True' and 'torch.set_deterministic(True)'?

Tags: pytorch, deterministic, reproducible-research

My network includes 'torch.nn.MaxPool3d' which throw a RuntimeError when cudnn deterministic flag is on according to the PyTorch docs (version 1.7 - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_deterministic.html#torch.set_deterministic), however, when I inserted the code 'torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True' at the beginning of my code, there was no RuntimeError. Why doesn't that code throw a RuntimeError?
I wonder whether that code guarantees the deterministic computation of my training process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True` *only* applies to CUDA convolution operations, and nothing else. Therefore, no, it will not guarantee that your training process is deterministic, since you're also using `torch.nn.MaxPool3d`, whose backward function is nondeterministic for CUDA.

`torch.set_deterministic()`, on the other hand, affects all the normally-nondeterministic operations listed here (note that `set_deterministic` has been renamed to `use_deterministic_algorithms` in 1.8): https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html?highlight=use_deterministic#torch.use_deterministic_algorithms

As the documentation states, some of the listed operations don't have a deterministic implementation. So if `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)` is set, they will throw an error.

If you need to use nondeterministic operations like `torch.nn.MaxPool3d`, then, at the moment, there is no way for your training process to be deterministic--unless you write a custom deterministic implementation yourself. Or you could open a GitHub issue requesting a deterministic  implementation: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues

In addition, you might want to check out this page: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Comment: this is gold: `As the documentation states, some of the listed operations don't have a deterministic implementation. So if torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) is set, they will throw an error.` Thanks I was confused about the errors I saw at one point.

Comment: if you're looking for the first line of the answer in the docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/backends.html#torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic "A bool that, if True, causes cuDNN to only use deterministic convolution algorithms."